# Finding $\cot(\beta)$, knowing $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=4/5$ and $\sin(\alpha-\beta)=3/5$

Tags: trigonometry

Let's assume that for $0<\beta<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \frac{4}{5}$, and $\sin(\alpha-\beta) = \frac{3}{5}$. Then, how could we find $\cot(\beta)$?

$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\sin(\alpha-\beta) = 2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \frac{7}{5}$$

$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)-\sin(\alpha-\beta) = 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha) = \frac{1}{5}$$

$$\tan(\alpha)\cot(\beta) = 7$$

But I am not sure where this would lead us.

Comment: You can also get the cosine of $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha-\beta$. Thanks to the inequality, these should have unique values. Then do similar things with those to what you've done already

Comment: FYI: Replacing $4/5$ and $3/5$ with $p/r$ and $q/r$, where $p^2+q^2=r^2$ and $p\geq q$, we have $$\cot\beta=\frac{p+q}{p-q}$$

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle \sin( a+b) =4/5\ \ \ \sin( a-b) =3/5.$
$\displaystyle So\ \cos( a+b) \ =\ 3/5$ but that means $\displaystyle \sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2} -( a+b)\right) =\sin( a-b) =3/5$
So $ $$\displaystyle \frac{\pi }{2} =a+b+a-b$
Or $\displaystyle a\ =\ \frac{\pi }{4}$
So $\cot(a) = 1 $
And since you have already figured out $\tan(a)\cot(b)=7$ so $\cot(b)=7$

Comment: Apologies, how did you conclude that $a+b+a-b = \displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2} $?

Comment: since the sine's of $pi/2-(a+b)$ and $a-b$ are equal so they should also be equal to each other. Or $pi/2-(a+b)=a-b$

Comment: Ahh, yes, that makes perfect sense! But this argument is only true under the assumption that $0<\beta<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$, right?

Comment: yes thats correct... otherwise you would also have to consider the other Quadrant angles also

Comment: Sure, exactly. Thanks for your so valuable thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sin ^2(\alpha+\beta)+\sin ^2(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{16}{25}+\frac{9}{25}=1 \\
\Rightarrow \quad & \sin ^2(\alpha+\beta)=1-\sin ^2(\alpha-\beta)=\cos ^2(\alpha-\beta)\\ \Rightarrow \quad & 
(\sin \alpha \cos \beta+\sin \beta \cos \alpha)^2=(\cos \alpha \cos \beta+\sin \alpha \sin \beta)^2 \\\Rightarrow \quad &\left(\cos ^2 \beta-\sin ^{2} \beta\right)\left(\cos ^2 \alpha-\sin ^{2} \alpha\right)=0 \\ \Rightarrow \quad 
&\cos ^2 \beta=\sin ^2 \beta \quad \textrm{  or }\cos ^2 \alpha=\sin ^2 \alpha \\\Rightarrow \quad & \cot\beta =1 \textrm{ or } \tan \alpha =1 \\ \Rightarrow \quad & \cot \beta=1 \quad \textrm{ or } \quad  7 \quad \textrm{ (By }\tan \alpha \cot \beta = 7)
\end{aligned}
$$